# How to calculate MKMapView area?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I know the center coordinate (latitude, longitude). How to calculate top left coordinate and bottom right coordinate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try

– convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView:

> convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView:
>   Converts a point in the specified
>   view’s coordinate system to a map
>   coordinate.
>
> - (CLLocationCoordinate2D)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point
>     toCoordinateFromView:(UIView *)view
>     Parameters point The point you want to
>     convert. view The view that serves as
>     the reference coordinate system for
>     the point parameter. Return Value The
>     map coordinate at the specified point.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 3.0 and
>   later. Declared In MKMapView.h

shani